# Trying to load a video file with ffmpeg using javacv

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to load a video file with javacv but I am facing some problems.

I managed to compile an application that will show an image on screen so I assume that my setup is ok.

The code I am using is the following.

```
import java.io.File;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;

public class TestCV{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File f = new File("input.mp4");
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f);

        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image");

        canvas.showImage(grabber.grab());

    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\takas\AppData\Local\Temp\jniavutil3690549951281752227.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:337)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:271)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil.<clinit>(avutil.java:76)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:291)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:87)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.<init>(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:73)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.<init>(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:69)
    at tester.t.JavaFlow.main(JavaFlow.java:13)
```

Do I have to use separate ffmpeg dlls? There is one ffmpeg dll in the opecv bin folder.

If I have to do this I will need a better way to include them using eclipse. Until now I just add the folder to path variable. For example I added this to make opencv work.

> C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;

Comment: did u get the answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

some days back i got same error and i solved this by following procedure,

download ffmpeg precompiled file for windows

for window 32
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/ffmpeg-0.7.1-win32-shared.7z

for window 64
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-0.7.1-win64-shared.7z

extract folder some where on hard-disk copy all dlls put them into system32 folder. basically these dll required to be in you path so that java program can access them